# Landscape and Vertical images in GridView (how to auto crop/scale)

Tags: android, user-interface, gridview, imageview

I want to present all thumbnails on device to the user, in a GridView where each "cell" is an ImageView. If all photos are *landscape* orientation, this looks good: Each thumbnail is rectangular and cropped to same size (I assume this is how the thumbnails are generated/stored on the device).

However, *vertically* oriented photos (and thumbnails) cause problems. The tall thumbnail stretches the cell, making the UI look bad:

[image: Messy UI]
Messy UI

[image: Neat UI]
Neat UI

What's a good and convenient way to handle this? Perhaps I should simply set some max height on the ImageViews, manually cropping (or scaling) the vertical thumbs? Should something like this be done in XML, or in Java code?

> **Update:** Another odd thing, is device-dependency (as always). The images above are from an emulator (Nexus 7), while here's how the same app looks on my (physical) Sony Xperia Z1 compact. Note that all vertical thumbnails (and images) are **automatically rotated**, such that all thumbs have same, tall size... 
>   [image]

Here are the relevant files:

### layout/fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PhotoFragment">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:id="@+id/listview_photo"
        style="@style/ForecastListStyle"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

### layout/grid_item_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_photo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### PhotoFragment.java

```
public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private final static int LOADER_ID = 87;
    private PhotoAdapter mPhotoAdapter;
    private GridView mGridView;

    // these are the data we want from MediaStore
    private final static String[] THUMBNAIL_COLUMNS = {
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_THUMB_ID,
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_DATA,
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_ID
    };

    static final int COL_THUMB_ID = 0;
    static final int COL_THUMB_DATA = 1;
    static final int COL_THUMB_IMAGE_ID = 2;

    public PhotoFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mPhotoAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_photo);
        gridView.setAdapter(mPhotoAdapter);

        mEmptyView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_empty);
        mGridView = gridView;

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        Uri thumbs_uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), thumbs_uri, THUMBNAIL_COLUMNS,
                null,null,  // read everything (all thumbnails)
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        int antall = 0;
        if (cursor != null) 
            mPhotoAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
        mPhotoAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

}
```

### PhotoAdapter.java

```
public class PhotoAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public PhotoAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item_gallery, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        long imgId = cursor.getLong(PhotoFragment.COL_THUMB_ID);

        String thumbData = cursor.getString(PhotoFragment.COL_THUMB_DATA);
        Bitmap thumbBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbData);
        viewHolder.iconView.setImageBitmap(thumbBitmap);
        viewHolder.lbl.setText("Photo " + imgId);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public final ImageView iconView;
        public final TextView lbl;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_photo);
            lbl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a solution could be to set android:layout_height="sizeThatYouLike" in your ImageView from the xml file

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it not a correct solution? Please, explain why. I'm still learning and an explanation would help me. Thanks

Comment: If I set layout_width="100dp" and layout_height="100dp", I do get square thumbnails, yes. Don't know why your suggestion has been downvoted... But is this the best way to do this? For `numColumns=4`, as I have now, this looks fine, but what if the number of columns changes?

To adjust layout to screen size and orientation, I've extracted the actual number of columns into `values/integers.xml` (4), `values-sw600dp/integers.xml` (4), and `values-sw720dp-land/integers.xml` (6). **Is it possible to set image size to something like,** `screenWidth/@integer/number_thumb_columns` ?

Comment: set layout_width="match_parent" and layout_height="100dp"

Comment: That seems to do the trick, yes :-) Now the thumbnails have width proportional to the column width! So, if I decrease the number of columns, the thumbnails are wider, and vice versa. Thanks!